# Rtk query graphql file upload

Tags: reactjs, graphql, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Doing my first app with redux toolkit and rtk query.

I have `"@rtk-query/graphql-request-base-query": "^2.1.0",` and `"graphql-request": "^4.2.0",` I get mutations and queries working but cannot figure out how to properly do the file upload. I know how to do with a setup of apollo client but not sure how it should be done here maybe someone has an idea or could give a hint ? the backend expects graphql upload type.

Comment: Does this help? https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-add-file-upload-to-your-graphql-api-34d51e341f38